# Is it possible to query appointment custom form data using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, outlook-calendar

I'm trying to get the values defined in a user created custom form (custom form designed in Outlook for calendar events, pictured below) via Microsofts Graph API.

[image: Outlook form custom form design view]

I've been digging through the documentation for a while now and cannot find anything that would let me do that. I want to get a specific event and get the values defined in the custom form.

Also queried the various extension and schema endpoints and not a trace of the custom data.

Is this even possible with the Graph api?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, the values from custom form cannot be obtained by Graph. Although no official docs states this.

If you cannot get the information by the **expand=fields** too, I'd suggest you to submit a feature request first: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

Comment: "Could not find a property named 'fields' on type 'microsoft.graph.event'." fields doesn't seem to be available for the event resource.